# Using Class Module in VBA give error

Tags: vba

I get an "object variable or With block variable not set " error in the following
code. Th line that gets the error is
    all = GetPayAllocation(rsPrj, 10, 1)

If I check the properties of the all variable they have values.

Any ideas?

```
Public Function tmptest1()

    Dim rsPrj As Recordset
    If Not Connection Then Exit Function
    gSQL = "SELECT * FROM Projects WHERE ProjectID=7893"
    If Not GetODBCRecordset(gSQL, rsPrj) Then Exit Function
    Dim all As PayAllocation
    all = GetPayAllocation(rsPrj, 10, 1)

    Debug.Print all.ManagementFee
    CloseALL
End Function

Public Function GetPayAllocation(rsPrj As Recordset, invHours As Double, invweeksofpay As Integer) As PayAllocation
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim all As PayAllocation
    Set all = New PayAllocation
    If Not all.Calculate(rsPrj, invHours, invweeksofpay) Then GoTo ErrExit

    Set GetPayAllocation = all

ErrExit:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    GeneralErrorHandler ("GetPayAllocation")
    Resume ErrExit
End Function
```

This the PayAllocation class module

```
Public PayRate As Double
Public Margin As Double
Public ManagementFee As Double
Public PayrollTax As Double
Public AgencyCommission As Double
Public Total As Double

Public Function Calculate(rsPrj As Recordset, invHours As Double, invweeksofpay As Integer) As Boolean

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim multiplier As Double
multiplier = GetMultiplierValue(rsPrj, invHours, invweeksofpay)

PayRate = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!PayRateInclSuper)
Total = PayRate

If rsPrj!MarginRateInclInPayRate = False Then
    If rsPrj!MarginRatePercent Then
        Margin = GetValue(rsPrj!MarginRate, PayRate)
    Else
        Margin = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!MarginRate)
    End If
    Total = Total + Margin
End If

If rsPrj!LMFInclInPayRate = False Then
    If rsPrj!LMFPercent Then
        ManagementFee = GetValue(rsPrj!LMF, PayRate)
    Else
        ManagementFee = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!LMF)
    End If
    Total = Total + ManagementFee
End If

If rsPrj!PayrollTaxInclInPayRate = False Then
    If rsPrj!PayrollTaxPercent Then
        PayrollTax = GetValue(rsPrj!PayrolltaxAmount, PayRate)
    Else
        PayrollTax = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!PayrolltaxAmount)
    End If
    Total = Total + PayrollTax
End If

If rsPrj!AgencyCommInclInPayRate = False Then
    If rsPrj!AgencyCommPercent Then
        AgencyCommission = GetValue(rsPrj!AgencyComm, PayRate)
    Else
        AgencyCommission = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!AgencyComm)
    End If
    Total = Total + AgencyCommission
End If


If rsPrj!MarginRateOnTop Then
    If rsPrj!MarginRatePercent Then
        Margin = GetValue(rsPrj!MarginRate, Total)
    Else
        Margin = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!MarginRate)
    End If
    Total = Total + Margin
End If

If rsPrj!LMFOnTop Then
    If rsPrj!LMFPercent Then
        ManagementFee = GetValue(rsPrj!LMF, Total)
    Else
        ManagementFee = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!LMF)
    End If
    Total = Total + ManagementFee
End If

If rsPrj!PayrollTaxOnTop Then
    If rsPrj!PayrollTaxPercent Then
        PayrollTax = GetValue(rsPrj!PayrolltaxAmount, Total)
    Else
        PayrollTax = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!PayrolltaxAmount)
    End If
    Total = Total + PayrollTax
End If

If rsPrj!AgencyCommOnTop Then
    If rsPrj!AgencyCommPercent Then
        AgencyCommission = GetValue(rsPrj!AgencyComm, Total)
    Else
        AgencyCommission = GetValue(multiplier, rsPrj!AgencyComm)
    End If
    Total = Total + AgencyCommission
End If

Calculate = True

ErrExit:
    Exit Function
ErrHandler:
    Calculate = False
    Resume ErrExit
End Function

Private Function GetMultiplierValue(rsPrj As Recordset, invHours As Double, invweeksofpay As Integer) As Double

    Dim value As Double

    Select Case rsPrj!HourlyDailyMthly
        Case "Hourly"
            value = invHours
        Case "Daily"
            value = invHours
        Case "Weekly"
            value = CDbl(invweeksofpay)
        Case "Monthly"
    End Select

    GetMultiplierValue = value

End Function

Private Function GetValue(multiplier As Double, amount As Double)

     GetValue = format(multiplier * amount, "0.00")

End Function
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you've posted here... Yet, it appears the explanation may come from yet another piece of code: that of the GetODBCRecordset() function.

Answer (score 2):

It should have been.

```
Set all = GetPayAllocation(rsPrj, 10, 1)
```